# How to send Message in Node.js theough Postfix mail server?

Tags: node.js, smtp, postfix-mta

I have some web application running on **ubuntu 18.04** using **node.js** server.
I configured my **postfix** mail server. but sometimes when i try to send some emails using this part of code, messages are not sent (specially for **Yahoo! mail** ).

```
const sendmail = require('sendmail')({
    logger: {
      debug: console.log,
      info: console.info,
      warn: console.warn,
      error: console.error
    },
    silent: false,
    smtpPort: 25, // Default: 25
    smtpHost: 'mail.mydomain.com' // Default: -1 - extra smtp host after resolveMX
  })


  sendmail({
     from: 'register@mydomain.com',
     to: data.Email,
     subject: 'Your Account Data',
     html: 'some message text',
   }, function(err, reply) {
     console.log(err && err.stack);
     console.dir(reply);
   });
```

BTW. gmail says this on my message:

```
gmail couldn't verify that mydomain.com actually sent this message.
```